# Rewrite not working on IIS like I'd expect

Tags: iis-7, url-rewrite-module, arr

I have the following redirect

```
<rules>
    <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="a/(.*)/(.*)" />
        <action type="Rewrite" url="https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/subfolder/{R:1}/{R:2}.o8d" />
    </rule>
</rules>
```

What I am trying to do is I have a url `http://www.mysite.com/a/username/filename`.
I want that to rewrite to `https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/subfolder/username/filename.o8d`

Currently I get a 404 error when visiting the url's I expect to work.

Any ideas?

Ok an update. I've tried changing `<action type="Rewrite" url="https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/subfolder/{R:1}/{R:2}.o8d" />` to `<action type="Rewrite" url="/" />` and it rewrites to the root of my site just fine. I have arr installed, and I repaired and restarted. Not sure what to do here. Everything I keep reading says this should be doable, but it isn't working.

It's like the rewritter is automatically setting the rewrite to `http://www.mysite.com/{Rewrite URL}`

Comment: See the links in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20886420/using-url-rewrite-for-cross-domain-http-requests